# Nested loop (level: beginner)

Tags: c#

[image]The task is to create a kind of thermostat that check the water temp. (its just an assignment).
I need a loop (loop1) that quits if "Q" button is pressed, inside that loop there is another  loop (loop2) with 2 conditions that always returns to loop1 (regardless of what condition is being met, its just a different message that will be displayed). I wrote some code but there is a bug in it and I cant figure it out what the problem is. Plz help.
P.S. I'm just a beginner so please don't judge too hard.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int temperature;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            temperature = Convert.ToInt32(choice);
            if (temperature < 17 || temperature > 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temp is {0} and its too cold to take a bath", temperature);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp again");
                //temperature = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }


            else if (choice == "Q")
                break;

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temp is MADE TO 20, thou it is {0}, its ok to bath", temperature);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp");
                temperature = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }                
        }            
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean *" there is a bug in it"*? What happens when you compile and execute this code?

Comment: "I cant figure it out what the problem is."  You may not know what the cause of the problem is, but you should be able to tell us what the effects are, so that way we don't have to guess.  Also, this won't even compile.  You have `else if ... else` not preceded by an `if`.

Comment: Your second while should be an if, and you don't need the readlines in the if statements at all..

Comment: @Martina Ok, but then I get another problem when I press Q to exit:
+  $exception {"Input string was not in a correct format."} System.FormatException
  args {string[0]} string[]
  temperature 40 int
  choice "q" string

Comment: @BACON
I corrected that misstake but there is another error when I try to run, this time when pressing Q to exit, it says: + $exception {"Input string was not in a correct format."} System.FormatException args {string[0]} string[] temperature 40 int choice "q" string –

Comment: Why do you refer to 2 loops, when there is only one?

Comment: That's because you are calling `Convert.ToInt32(choice)` always, including when you enter "Q". You should first check if it's "Q", or even better, use `Int32.TryParse` so you can validate it's a valid integer. You should run your code step by step to understand what's going on. If you did, you would have seen that when you entered "Q" the code never reached the "Q" condition (it exits the program if you enter any invalid integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int temperature;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            if (choice.ToUpper().Equals("Q"))
                break;
            temperature = Convert.ToInt32(choice);
            if (temperature < 17 || temperature > 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temp is {0} and its too {1} to take a bath", temperature, temperature < 17 ? "cold" : "hot");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temp is MADE TO 20, thou it is {0}, its ok to bath", temperature);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you enter W, A, P, -, ?, or any other letter, this will throw an exception.

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot. Have beed struggling with this task the hole day and couldn't figure it out!
By the way, what does this piece of code mean: ToUpper().Equals("Q")  ?

Comment: I means that your "choice" variable will be converted to uppercase

Comment: @Andrew, it doesn't matter, the task doesn't ask to handle that kind of input

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate wheather "choice" is equal to "Q" before trying to convert it to an int.

You are getting the exception because you are trying to convert "Q" to int.

Also considder calling ".ToUpper()" on your choice check so you don't only check for lowercase OR uppercase.

```
if (choice.ToUpper() == "Q")
    break;

temperature = Convert.ToInt32(choice);
if (temperature < 17 || temperature > 25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Temp is {0} and its too cold to take a bath", temperature);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp again");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Temp is MADE TO 20, thou it is {0}, its ok to bath", temperature);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp");
    temperature = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You should be aware that typing in any other character than "Q" will throw an exception.

Consider using the int.TryParse() method to check wheather the user input can be parsed to an int.

Comment: No need to use an `else` as the `break` already exits from the loop. Also, remember to indent your code. :P

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written this  code for you, Removing the logical and run-time errors, please have a look at this one. This is exact according to your statement !.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {
            while (true)
            {
                int temperature;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the temp");
                string choice = Console.ReadLine();

                if ( int.TryParse(choice, out temperature))
                {

                    if (temperature < 17 || temperature > 25)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Temp is {0} and its too cold to take a bath", temperature);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Temp is MADE TO 20, thou it is {0}, its ok to bath", temperature);
                    }

                }
                else if(choice != "Q" && choice != "q")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n * Invalid Entry * ");
                }



                if (choice == "Q" || choice== "q")
                    break;


            }
        }
```

Comment: You should avoid duplicating the conditions.

Comment: I don't Think I have duplicated any condition from any where :)

Comment: `if(choice!="Q" || choice!="q")` is always `true`. You mean `&&`

Comment: Yes, you are checking `choice` against "Q" twice, and you are checking that even if you already know that the user entered a number. If the exit letter is changed to "X", you would have to do the modification in more than one place (= bad). You could just do `else break;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
while (true)
{
    int temperature = 0;
    string choice;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the temperature: ");
        choice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice.ToUpper().Equals("Q"))
            return;

    } while (Int32.TryParse(choice, out temperature) == false);

    if (temperature < 17 || temperature > 25)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temp is {0} and its too {1} to take a bath", temperature, temperature < 17 ? "cold" : "hot");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temp is MADE TO 20, thou it is {0}, it's ok to bath", temperature);
    }
}
```

Here the application asks for a temperature until you enter "Q" or a valid integer. Note that to exit from both loops I'm simply using a `return`, as this should be in a small method. If your logic continued after the outer `while`, you should move it into another method.